# Create a vertical toggle with height adjustment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I belive i am close. My toggle works perfectly horizontally however, not vertically. When my toggle is vertical the toggled information is only viewable under the 3rd toggle, not directly under its assigned toggle header(hope this makes sense - seen in coding) i can't seem to add a adjustable height for the toggle either, I've tired numerous ways none work. I want to make the height the height of the content. any help will be appreciated.

```js
 var divs = ["Soft", "Broch", "tut"];
    var visibleDivId = null;

    function toggleVisibility(divId) {
      if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
      } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
      }

      hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }

    function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
      var i, divId, div;

      for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);

        if(visibleDivId === divId) {
          div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Soft');">soft</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Broch');">broch</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('tut');">tut</a>
  
  <div id="Soft"  style="display: none;">Soft div</div>
  <div id="Broch" style="display: none;">broch div</div>
  <div id="tut"   style="display: none;">tut div</div>
```

The toggle function works fine. Press one toggle the others are inactive. any suggestions will be extremely helpful

Comment: Do you mean that you want the word "Soft div" written under the toggle named "soft" when it's turned on? What exactly do you mean by adjustable height for the toggle?

Comment: Yeah that correct. Each toggle is going to hold far more information then it currently is, and I've been having a problem with all the information showing, so was wondering if i could change the height for each toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't just changing the order in the dom enough?

```
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Soft');">soft</a>
  <div id="Soft" style="display: none;">Soft div</div>

  <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Broch');">broch</a>
  <div id="Broch" style="display: none;">broch div</div>

  <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('tut');">tut</a>
  <div id="tut" style="display: none;">tut div</div>
```

Comment: oh wow that simple. you can tell I'm new to this right. Thank you so much